# GitLab doesnt work anymore since Docker/Discourse installation

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gitlab, discourse

i used to have a always uptodate GitLab instance on my hardware server (Ubuntu 14.04).

However, i decided to install Discourse (or and Docker) lately and now GitLab isnt starting properly anymore.

When i run the service, the sidekiq process gets started but not the Unicorn worker:

```
git@host:~$ bash -x /etc/init.d/gitlab start
+ RAILS_ENV=production
+ app_user=git
+ app_root=/home/git/gitlab
+ pid_path=/home/git/gitlab/tmp/pids
+ socket_path=/home/git/gitlab/tmp/sockets
+ web_server_pid_path=/home/git/gitlab/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid
+ sidekiq_pid_path=/home/git/gitlab/tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid
+ test -f /etc/default/gitlab
+ . /etc/default/gitlab
++ RAILS_ENV=production
++ app_user=git
++ app_root=/home/git/gitlab
++ pid_path=/home/git/gitlab/tmp/pids
++ socket_path=/home/git/gitlab/tmp/sockets
++ web_server_pid_path=/home/git/gitlab/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid
++ sidekiq_pid_path=/home/git/gitlab/tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid
+ '[' git '!=' git ']'
+ cd /home/git/gitlab
+ check_pids
+ mkdir -p /home/git/gitlab/tmp/pids
+ '[' -f /home/git/gitlab/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid ']'
++ cat /home/git/gitlab/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid
+ wpid=8688
+ '[' -f /home/git/gitlab/tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid ']'
++ cat /home/git/gitlab/tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid
+ spid=2923
+ case "$1" in
+ start_gitlab
+ check_stale_pids
+ check_status
+ check_pids
+ mkdir -p /home/git/gitlab/tmp/pids
+ '[' -f /home/git/gitlab/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid ']'
++ cat /home/git/gitlab/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid
+ wpid=8688
+ '[' -f /home/git/gitlab/tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid ']'
++ cat /home/git/gitlab/tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid
+ spid=2923
+ '[' 8688 -ne 0 ']'
+ kill -0 8688
+ web_status=1
+ '[' 2923 -ne 0 ']'
+ kill -0 2923
+ sidekiq_status=0
+ '[' 1 = 0 -a 0 = 0 ']'
+ gitlab_status=3
+ '[' 8688 '!=' 0 -a 1 '!=' 0 ']'
+ echo 'Removing stale Unicorn web server pid. This is most likely caused by the web server crashing the last time it ran.'
Removing stale Unicorn web server pid. This is most likely caused by the web server crashing the last time it ran.
+ rm /home/git/gitlab/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid
+ '[' 2923 '!=' 0 -a 0 '!=' 0 ']'
+ '[' 1 '!=' 0 -a 0 '!=' 0 ']'
+ '[' 1 '!=' 0 ']'
+ echo -n 'Starting GitLab Unicorn'
Starting GitLab Unicorn+ '[' 1 = 0 ']'
+ rm -f /home/git/gitlab/tmp/sockets/gitlab.socket
+ RAILS_ENV=production
+ bin/web start
master failed to start, check stderr log for details
+ '[' 0 = 0 ']'
+ echo 'The Sidekiq job dispatcher is already running with pid 2923, not restarting'
The Sidekiq job dispatcher is already running with pid 2923, not restarting
+ wait_for_pids
+ i=0
+ '[' '!' -f /home/git/gitlab/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid -o '!' -f /home/git/gitlab/tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid ']'
+ echo

+ print_status
+ check_status
+ check_pids
+ mkdir -p /home/git/gitlab/tmp/pids
+ '[' -f /home/git/gitlab/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid ']'
++ cat /home/git/gitlab/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid
+ wpid=9352
+ '[' -f /home/git/gitlab/tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid ']'
++ cat /home/git/gitlab/tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid
+ spid=2923
+ '[' 9352 -ne 0 ']'
+ kill -0 9352
+ web_status=0
+ '[' 2923 -ne 0 ']'
+ kill -0 2923
+ sidekiq_status=0
+ '[' 0 = 0 -a 0 = 0 ']'
+ gitlab_status=0
+ '[' 0 '!=' 0 -a 0 '!=' 0 ']'
+ '[' 0 = 0 ']'
+ echo 'The GitLab Unicorn web server with pid 9352 is running.'
The GitLab Unicorn web server with pid 9352 is running.
+ '[' 0 = 0 ']'
+ echo 'The GitLab Sidekiq job dispatcher with pid 2923 is running.'
The GitLab Sidekiq job dispatcher with pid 2923 is running.
+ '[' 0 = 0 -a 0 = 0 ']'
+ printf 'GitLab and all its components are \033[32mup and running\033[0m.\n'
GitLab and all its components are up and running.
+ exit
git@host:~$
```

And no, Docker doesn't try to bind on ports that are used by GitLab:

```
root@host ~ # netstat -tulpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3076/redis-server 1
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2940/nginx
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1330/sshd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3055/master
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2940/nginx
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1391/mysqld
tcp6       0      0 :::2222                 :::*                    LISTEN      30087/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      30094/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      2940/nginx
tcp6       0      0 :::4949                 :::*                    LISTEN      1168/perl
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1330/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN      3055/master
tcp6       0      0 :::1311                 :::*                    LISTEN      2518/dsm_om_connsvc
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:51367           0.0.0.0:*                           1911/openvpn
```

Nginx is running, but only shows:

"502 - GitLab is not responding."

Can someone help me out?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your log seems to make it sound like Gitlab is starting successfully. And nginx is listening. I'm thinking it's something with the unix socket that Gitlab uses between unicorn and nginx.

Comment: @StevenV any idea to troubleshoot that socket? I'm not sure how to approach here.

Comment: When gitlab is running, a file should be at `/home/git/gitlab/tmp/sockets/gitlab.socket` which is what nginx uses to communicate to GitLab. If that's there, do a once over on the permissions and ensure nginx is setup correctly for GitLab. Beyond that you may want to ask on the [GitLab support forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/gitlabhq) to see if they have specific things to try.

Comment: Got it working. Added an answer below. Thank you @StevenV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the problem.

I somehow overlooked the message in the bash debug output:

`master failed to start, check stderr log for details`

So I opened `/home/git/gitlab/log/unicorn.stderr.log.1` and I saw the following:

```
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/lib/unicorn/socket_helper.rb:147:in `initialize': Address already in use - bind(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 8080 (Errno::EADDRINUSE)
```

And then it hit me: The Nginx of Discourse is using the same port as GitLab's unicorn workers - 8080

I adjusted that port and voilà, everything works again.